# RecyclerView throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to insert multiple items and notifying the adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get unique numbers from call logs of a user and show them in a `RecyclerView`. By unique I mean if I have shown the number, or corresponding contact once in the list, I have to skip the item. And I want to use a `Cursor` for showing this to make the rendering quick.

To do this, I have implemented a `RecyclerView` Adapter which looks like this (Only showing the relevant code, **kotlin**)

```
class CallAdapter(val activity: Activity, var cursor: Cursor) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CallAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


        val handler = Handler()
        val contacts = ArrayList<Contact>()

        init {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            UniqueLogs(this).start()
        }

        companion object {
            const val TAG = "CallAdapter"
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
            val binding = CallLogItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return contacts.count()
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val contact = contacts[position]

            ...

            cursor.moveToNext()
        }

        class ViewHolder(val binding: CallLogItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

        class UniqueLogs(val adapter: CallLogAdapterShobhit) : Thread() {
            private var available = true
            private val cursor = adapter.cursor
            private val hash: HashMap<String, Int> = HashMap<String, Int>()
            private val contacts = adapter.contacts
            private var count = 0

            override fun run() {
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                while (available && cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    var contact = adapter.getCurrentItemContact()

                    while (available && hash[contact.phoneNumber] == 1) {
                        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            contact = adapter.getCurrentItemContact()
                        } else {
                            available = false
                        }
                    }

                    if (available) {
                        contacts.add(contact)
                        val position = count
                        count += 1

                        adapter.handler.post({
                            Log.d(TAG, "Position: $position Size: ${adapter.itemCount}")
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(position)
                        })

                        hash[contact.phoneNumber] = 1
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I am getting an exception which looks like this :-

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{c75176c position=5 id=-1, oldPos=4, pLpos:4 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached not recyclable(1) no parent}
```

The `position`, `id`, `oldPos`, `pLpos`, etc. are different every time but  the error is essentially the same.

I've tried writing logs as well to make sure that I am not trying to insert an element before the element is added to `contacts` array list, but the logs say that all's well.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: i'll use this like `eventsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` it's work for me

Comment: @MohammadAli Wouldn't that produce a jittering effect because it keeps rendering the whole list?

Comment: You're calling `contacts.add(contact)` from a different thread. ArrayList is not thread safe by default, try it with something like  `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<YourClassNameHere>())`

Comment: @LanceToth getting the same error.

Comment: @Shobhit then maybe try `adapter.contacts.add(contact)` ?

Comment: @LanceToth Didn't work. It's the same reference anyway.

Comment: Maybe this might help then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759171/recyclerview-and-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected-in

Comment: @LanceToth wow that actually worked!

Comment: @Shobhit glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the data in a background thread, but notifying on the main thread. By the time the notification happens, you may have further altered the data. I would suggest that you do all your updates on the background and then just do a generic `notifyDataSetChanged` when everything is done.

Another option would be to calculate the entire new list in a background thread and then update the real data once and notify in the main thread.

Comment: I don't want to do that. I wouldn't need a Thread if I wanted to bring all the data in memory together and then render them. I need to sort of "lazy load" contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the data and calling `notifyItemInserted` should synchronously or you will have inconsistent data.

Putting `contacts.add(contact)` just before `notifyItemInserted` should solve it.

```
                    adapter.handler.post({
                        Log.d(TAG, "Position: $position Size: ${adapter.itemCount}")
                        contacts.add(contact)
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(position)
                    })
```

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. Handling the exception in a try-catch solved it!