# Use cases of removeall and removeif

Tags: java, kotlin

I found this:

```
fun main() {
    val list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    list.removeAll { x -> x in 1..3 } // [4, 5]
    list.removeIf { x -> x in 1..3 } // [4, 5]
}
```

Both of them yield the same result.

Though I understand that `removeAll` is Kotlin and `removeIf` is Java but I don't understand why `removeAll` is there when `removeIf` was already there?

And for the fact that we could use `removeIf` in Kotlin without any hassle. Or is there any use case that might need one over another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are very very different functions, but in kotlin the method is overloaded, it means, it has two different types of arguments for the function.

If you read the doc, you can see that you can use this function by giving a collection:

```
fun <T> MutableCollection<out T>.removeAll(
    elements: Collection<T>
): Boolean (source)
```

Or giving a function to filter:

```
fun <T> MutableIterable<T>.removeAll(
    predicate: (T) -> Boolean
): Boolean (source)
```

So, the second one is like the Java version of removeIf, the first one is not.

Answer (score 17):

Java's `removeIf()` is there since Java 1.8.

Kotlin started at 2011 ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))). Java 1.8 appeared in 2014.

I'm not sure when the Kotlin's `removeAll(predicate)` was specified and implemented, however it probably predates Java's `removeIf()`.

Comment: what follows for Android is that Java's removeIf is only available for API 24+ whereas Kotlin's removeAll will run on older APIs

Answer (score 17):

There is one more important difference:

Calling `removeIf` on a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is **thread-safe**, but `removeAll` is **not**.

Looking at the code, `removeIf` has a custom implementation for `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but `removeAll` **iterates over the indices** and will end up throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or even worse, **removing the wrong element**, if called concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

> Both of them yield the same result.

The result is achieved in completely different ways, so it might not always be quite same.

`removeAll` is a convenience method. It's a simple loop calling `removeAt` multiple times.

`removeIf` is a native `ArrayList` method that directly manipulates internal `elementData`, bypassing all the older removal methods and any logic that might have been put there. The bad news here is that it got retroactively blanket-applied to everything that derives from `ArrayList`, disregarding older implementations.

> Or is there any use case that might need one over another?

One example is `androidx.databinding.ObservableList`, which predates `removeIf`, and doesn't send due removal notifications, thus either breaking your code **silently** or causing [cryptic errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75401082/1059969).