# How to reproduce a bug?

Tags: android, testing, android-recyclerview

My application sometimes crashes on some devices, with this error:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected

After some changes and spend a couple of hours, not sure if it fixed or not.

I read some of the answers and did what they say .like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759171/recyclerview-and-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected-in).

But how do I sure if the changes are working while I don't know when the exceptions occur?
How to create a situation that leads to the exception?

Comment: Use Crashlytics to see on which line an error happens. Crashlytics also supports breadcrumbs to some extend

Comment: @zun I'm using Crashlitycs.This exception happen when number of items changed.So you cant know which line makes it crash.