# Coroutines, async DiffUtil and Inconsistency detected error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, android-diffutils

I'm having trouble putting up together Kotlin Flows and async DiffUtil.

I have this function in my RecyclerView.Adapter that computes on a computation thread a DiffUtil and dispatch updates to the RecyclerView on the Main thread :

```
suspend fun updateDataset(newDataset: List<Item>) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val diff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback()
        {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean
                    = dataset[oldItemPosition].conversation.id == newDataset[newItemPosition].conversation.id

            override fun getOldListSize(): Int = dataset.size
            override fun getNewListSize(): Int = newDataset.size

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean
                    = dataset[oldItemPosition] == newDataset[newItemPosition]
        })

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            dataset = newDataset // <-- dataset is the Adapter's dataset
            diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this@ConversationsAdapter)
        }
    }
```

I call this function from my Fragment like this :

```
private fun updateConversationsList(conversations: List<ConversationsAdapter.Item>)
{
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        (listConversations.adapter as ConversationsAdapter).updateDataset(conversations)
    }
}
```

`updateConversationsList()` is called multiple times within a very short period of time because this function is called by Kotlin's `Flows` like `Flow<Conversation>`.

Now with all that, I'm sometimes getting a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder` error. Reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759171/recyclerview-and-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected-in) I understand that it is a threading problem and I've read lots of recommendation like [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37030377#comment20) that all say : the thread that updates the dataset of the Adapter and the thread that dispatches updates to the RecyclerView must be the same.

As you can see, I already respect this by doing :

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    dataset = newDataset
    diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this@ConversationsAdapter)
}
```

Since the Main thread, and only it, does these two operations, how is it possible that I get this error ?

Comment: A couple of thoughts. 1. Have you looked in to `ListAdapter` and `DiffUtil.ItemCallback`? 2. Square is working on [`cycler`](https://github.com/square/cycler) which uses `DiffUtil` and coroutines to do exactly what you want, it may be a good source for reference.

Comment: Thank you for cycler, I didn't know about it it looks interesting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your diff is racing. If your update comes twice in short period this can happen:

```
Adapter has dataset 1 @Main
Dataset 2 comes
calculateDiff between 1 & 2 @Async
Dataset 3 comes
calculateDiff between 1 & 3 @Async
finished calculating diff between 1 & 2 @ Async
finished calculating diff between 1 & 3 @ Async
Dispatcher main starts handling messages
replace dataset 1 with dataset 2 using 1-2 diff @Main
replace dataset 2 with dataset 3 using 1-3 diff @Main - inconsistency
```

Alternative scenario is diff between 1-3 can finish before 1-2 but issue remains the same.
You have to cancel ongoing calculation when new one comes and prevent deploying invalid diff, for example store job reference inside your fragment:

```
var updateJob : Job? = null

private fun updateConversationsList(conversations: List<ConversationsAdapter.Item>)
{
    updateJob?.cancel()
    updateJob = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        (listConversations.adapter as ConversationsAdapter).updateDataset(conversations)
    }
}
```

If you cancel it then `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` will internally check continuation state and won't run.

Comment: Clear explanation and clean solution. Thank you

Comment: @Pawel Hey can you please look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72742819/11560810)

Comment: Hi @Pawel,
I get screen flickering because of calling updateConversationsList too many times from my flow any recommendations ?

Comment: There is a risk if job gets cancelled after:

dataset = newDataset 
but before:
diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this@ConversationsAdapter)

Comment: @Cppcrusaders there's no risk because cancellation state is not checked there. If you're using flow you're probably using `collectLatest` and don't really need to keep the track of a job like in this answer, if you experience flickering you can try to `debounce` your flow or wrap `DiffUtil.calculateDiff(...)` call with `runInterruptible`.

Comment: Debounce is a great solution..
The following scenario makes me nervous..
1> we set dataset = dataset_v2 [so new state]
2> before we could apply  he diff by diff.dispatchUpdatesTo the coroutine is cancelled
3> new dataset (lets call it is dataset_v3) is now diffed with dataset_v2 and will be applied to UI... but what was expected was it to be diffed against dataset

Comment: @Cppcrusaders as I said in previous comment, it won't happen because coroutine cancellation is cooperative and nothing checks cancellation state in between those 2 calls .