# Android java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This question ask many times, but i cant understand properly,
Here i am used Sqlite Database for simple chatting purpose and its all raw populate with recyclerview.
What i had do ?

1. create class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
2. create method which return List
3. In Activity class create an instance of adapter class and pass List in adapter.

   public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   ```
   public List<SqlMessages> sqlMessagesList()
     {
     String  query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
       List<SqlMessages> messagesList=new LinkedList<>();
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
       SqlMessages sqlMessages;
           if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
               sqlMessages.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
               sqlMessages.setFromid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FROM)));
               sqlMessages.setType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TYPE)));
               sqlMessages.setMessage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MESSAGE)));
               sqlMessages.setTimestamp(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

               messagesList.add(sqlMessages);
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
       return messagesList;
   }
   ```

   }

Activity class

```
messagesAdapter=new MessagesAdapter(myDbHandler.sqlMessagesList());
```

when new message add

```
final SQLiteDatabase db= myDbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, messageText);
        values.put(COLUMN_FROM, MessageSenderId);
        values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, TYPE_TEXT);
        values.put(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP,tsLong);


        long rowInserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, values);
        if(rowInserted != -1)
        {
            Log.v("sqlitesave","ok");
            messagesAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myDbHandler.sqlMessagesList().size()-1);
            // to use of notifyItemInserted the app is crash(not every time but sometime) Logcat show below error
        }
         else
        {
            Log.v("sqlitesave","notok");
        }
        db.close();
```

LogCat

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{6cea9b9 position=15 id=-1, oldPos=14, pLpos:14 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{4aedc2 VFED..C.. ......I. 0,108-720,723 #7f080217 app:id/message_list_user}, adapter:".......".chat.MessagesAdapter@1cd2f63, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@25f8760, context:"........".chat.MessageActivity@cd7aab8
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5715)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5898)
```

I tried
 messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
it works perfect and this types of question all developers answer is use `notifyDataSetChanged` but for the further operarion i need to use of `notifyItemInserted` 
**So how to use notifyItemInserted in proper way withhandle this exception ?**

Comment: The error is probably coming from your MessagesAdapter, you need to provide its code here.

Comment: Hi Vora. Did you find the answer to your question? can you confirm that this crash happens on samsungs only like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50523415/7917629